# P channel to get input signal state

Tags: microcontroller, p-channel

I want to detect when a ground input is connected to my circuit.

My specs are, that when there is no ground signal then 0V needs to go to my microcontroller. When I have ground connected to my circuit then 5V needs to go to my microcontroller.

The method I choose was to use a simple P-channel MOSFET ([datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfr9120npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563607932138))

The MCU sees a Ground (0V) as a high and 1V to 30V as a low.

Is this correct to use this MOSFET for an application like this? The input signal occurs at random times so I am not PWMing the gate at a given frequency.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXubMN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is that 12V really running to your MCU?

Comment: Is the input ground only a short to ground or can also be via a range of resistance values to ground?

Comment: @SteKulov it is a short to ground, what happens if it is a range of resistance to ground?

Comment: Can you separate the LED indication to an output of the MCU instead? Wastes one pin but simplifies your problem.

Comment: @JoeyB  Then if the resistances get high enough the FET will not acheive the threshold voltage to turn on.  This is due to the voltage divider that will form between R2 and the sum of R1 plus whatever is connected.  Max threshold voltage is in the datasheet and you should treat it as your min requirement for turning it on.  Aim for even higher if you can to get a solid turn-on.

Answer (score 1):

When open, Vgs=Vds and the FET presents a constant voltage drop of this current limited by R1 by an amount equal to Vgs(th) where the FET is around 1k to 5K depending on the device datasheet. However, the ESD diodes are fast and tiny and cannot handle more than 5 mA typ. so you need to limit the voltage.  There is no need for the 12V side since they share a ground when connected.  However, your input Vgs might be at risk of exceeding specs or typical +/-15V.

So a Zener clamp or diode clamp to Vdd is all you need. If using Vdd =5V R1 can be smaller if necessary.

Although I think you are considering the Arduino board with 12V input rather than the 5V or 3.3V the IC uses.

Comment: 1. "However, the ESD diodes are fast and tiny and cannot handle more than 5 mA typ. so you need to limit the voltage" where do I limit this voltage? At the gate? 2. "When open, Vgs=Vds and the FET presents a constant voltage drop of this current limited by R1 by an amount equal to Vgs(th) where the FET is around 1k to 5K depending on the device datasheet" What is 1K to 5K? Is it resistance? 3. "However, your input Vgs might be at risk of exceeding specs or typical +/-15V" The datasheet says +/-20V. 4. "If using Vdd =5V R1 can be smaller if necessary." Yes 5V is also an option

Comment: Do not exceed Vdd on the uC. nor Vgs max = 15 V . But 5V is might  be enough to drive Vgs to pullup an LED with 10mA or more. Keep in mind std. FETS with Vgs = 2 to 4V the Rds is as high as 1k to 5k then reduces by square law above Vt

Comment: I see, the main application is not to turn on the LED. The LED is just there to visually see if the input was applied, so the LED does not have to be really that bright. So I will drop R1 to a much lower value. The main application is applying 5V to the uC when the input is grounded (i.e. MOSFET is ON) and 0V to the uC when the input is not grounded (i.e. MOSFET is OFF)

Comment: Understood.  List all the component limits for input and out then verify and stay below Abs. Max. then Consider ESD faults and Vcc faults.  Satisfying logic 0/1 is easy, ensuring it is reliable needs care

Answer (score 1):

One shortcoming of your circuit is the case when then input signal is in the 1V to 8V (roughly) range. With the PMOS' source set at 12V, a gate voltage of 7V for example, the transistor **would still be turned on** and the GPIO would read a logic 1. That is true for any voltage at the gate that makes the difference between gate and source *large* enough—that means that you wouldn't be able to distinguish between a 0V signal and one in the 1V to 8V range, depending on the transistor threshold voltage. This wouldn't be a problem if you knew the input signal was going to be either 0V or something at 12V or above, but the range below 12V is problematic with the transistor.

What you really want is to map a 0V to a logic 1 (High) and the ***whole*** 1V-30V to a logic 0 (Low), so you need to make that entire analog range into a discrete value. Here is one way to do that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f110Mv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The TLV3401 is comparator circuit that tolerates supply voltages of up to 15V and has an open-drain output. Notice the output going to the GPIO is pulled up to VCC, such that you can select any voltage that would be appropriate for the GPIO (e.g., 5V)—I'm skeptical you can pass 12V along to a GPIO.

Going back to the circuit, for inputs less than 1V, the output will be pulled high by R2 and for inputs greater than 1V, the the comparator will pull the output node low.

Notice that Zener2 sets a 1V reference to compare the input signal against and Zener1 is just to protect the comparator input against excessive voltage at its V- input terminal (it can tolerate up to VCC + 5V, so 17V in this case).

Comment: The only input signal is ground. No other input voltages go there. I do not think I made that very clear in my question. So if there isnt a ground input signal then the input will just float. So I assume I would need a pullup to the inverting input of the op amp

Comment: @JoeyB if that is the case, your circuit works. I thought you meant that the input signal could vary that much. In your circuit, the PMOS is overkill in the sense that it doesn't need to be rated for high currents, but it still would work. I would also put a pulldown resistor in parallel with the LED and its series resistor to make sure that the GPIO is pulled low when the PMOS is off. The LED plus R1 may not work as a pull down when the PMOS is off.

Comment: I have edited the circuit according to what I interpreted in your comment. Is the updated circuit correct?

Comment: @JoeyB Yes, that would work. You can make R4 10k or even 100k for better power efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

1. This MOSFET is an overkill here but will work.
2. Use the same supply for FET and internal MCU to avoid *lots* of problems
3. Place a resistor from MCU input to GND because the LED does not conduct below a color dependent minimum voltage (1.5-3V)
4. Place a capacitor parallel to R2 (e.g. 100nF) to protect the gate from ESD impacts.
5. Use a diode in series with R2 (cathode to input) to allow U(input) > 25V (gate voltage limit)